# Exponential distribution confusion

Tags: probability, statistics, exponential-distribution

The PDF of the exponential distribution is $\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$, the CDF is $1-e^{-\lambda x}$.

Assume that, $\lambda=0.8$, $x=0$.

Thus, $P(X \le 0)=1-e^{-0.8 \cdot 0}=0$, and  $P(X=0)=0.8e^{-0.8 \cdot 0}=0.8$.

$P(X<0)=P(X \le 0)-P(X=0)=0-0.8=-0.8$.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Given a r.v. X with probability density f(x) it is false that p(X=a)=f(a). It is true that given an interval I p(X in I)=int_I f(x)dx . This is the definition of a probability density. If the density is  continuous, the smaller the interval I the smaller the probability, so that p(X=a)=0

Comment: @Thomas, what PDF denotes then?

Comment: Your cdf/pdf is wrong.  Note the support of the exponential distributions is $\mathbb{R}^+$ and remember to use an appropriate piecewise definition.

Comment: https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter4/4_1_1_pdf.php or any introductory book on statistics. Note also the comments of user... .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For continuous random variables, $P(X=x)=0$ for any single point $x$. In particular this means that unlike the discrete case, we don’t have $P(X=x)=f(x)$.

What the density function is used for is that given a set $A$, we have $P(X\in A)=\int_A f(x) dx$.